# listen to headset button events in blackberry

Tags: bluetooth, event-handling, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, headset

I'm developing a blackberry app using WebWorks that should listen to a bluetooth headset button events , when the play button is pressed for example it should do something

I have been searching for days for a solution using webworks or ndk but I got no clue.

even if there is a workaround that would solve the problem because I'm not concerned about playing any audio, I just want to capture the event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the environment you are developing in. Assuming Native/Cascades you use the [NowPlayingConnection](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__multimedia__nowplayingconnection.html).

Comment: I'm using webworks, but if the only solution possible it in Native/Cascades I can write a plugin for cordova that implements this solution, will this class notify me of events even if there is no actual media playing ? from the name of it I don't think so.

Comment: It is ok for me to create a plugin for it, I know how to do that, so talking in Native/Cascades , do you think this would fire the event even if the device is not in the "Now Playing" mode i.e no music is actually playing ?

Comment: It would in the Native/Cascades environment. There are other BB10 applications that use this method. Only one application at a time can have an active "Now Playing" connection though.